# Linq Grouping Using Two Constraints

Tags: c#, linq

*A necessary disclaimer:  I am looking to help develop a better understanding of Linq so I'm attempting to take a real-world problem at work and solve it using Linq.  This doesn't mean I am making the assumption that Linq is better (faster, less memory, more readable, etc.) than a more straight-ahead procedural solution.  If anything, I'm trying to find the edges of Linq (and a functional style) with regard to my work.*

As part of a larger communications protocol, I have a `List<byte[]>`.  These `byte[]`'s are of variable size and each represents a request to some system.  These `byte[]`'s must be sent to the other system in the same sequence as in the `List<>`, but it's desirable to pack several `byte[]` requests into a single message to reduce communications overhead.  The payload of the message will be a single `byte[]` that is the concatenation of all the individual `byte[]`'s.

There are two constraints regarding this packing of `byte[]`'s.  The first is that we have an upper limit on the total number of bytes that can be sent (`maxSendBytes`).  The second is that each individual request will generate a variable-length response of some maximum length.  The sum of these response's maximum lengths can't be larger than another limit (`maxReceiveBytes`).  We can determine the maximum length of a response with a function called `LongestResponseLength` that accepts the `byte[]` of the request.

So, the ideal end result of this would be to convert one `List<byte[]>` that represents the individual requests to a one `List<byte[]>` where each `byte[]` is a single message payload composed of the concatenation of one or more `byte[]` requests.

Here is my procedural solution that may help people understand what I'm trying to do:

```
public static List<byte[]> PackList(List<byte[]> options, int maxSendBytes = 500, int maxReceiveBytes = 1500-200)
{
    var payloads = new List<byte[]>();      // each item is an outbound payload to put in a message
    var currentPayload = new List<byte>();  // payload we're accumulating on now
    var currentExpectedLength = 0;          // expected length of response payload

    foreach (var option in options)
    {
        var optionLength = LongestResponseLength(option);

        // add to current payload as long as neither limit hit

        if (currentPayload.Count + optionLength >= maxSendBytes ||
            currentExpectedLength + optionLength >= maxReceiveBytes)
        {
            payloads.Add(currentPayload.ToArray());     // add the payload to the list of payloads
            currentPayload = new List<byte>();          // start a new payload
            currentExpectedLength = 0;                  //   "
        }

        currentPayload.AddRange(option);
        currentExpectedLength += optionLength;
    }

    if (currentPayload.Count > 0)
    {
        payloads.Add(currentPayload.ToArray());
    }

    return payloads;
}
```

Are there better ways to express the above code?  Probably.  But that's not the question.

Comment: Your question has a bit of a `tl/dr` problem, and I'd like to suggest you add some code for both your attempt at the procedural solution and also your attempt at the LINQ based solution.  I think if you did that, this could be a great question.

Comment: can't you concatenate all the `bit[]` and then simply take as many bits as you want with `take`?

Comment: Well, yeah, I'll strip out all of the stuff that's in the code which is work-proprietary, but I wanted to avoid people taking that code apart and commenting on it.  I'll do that a bit later.

Comment: If you asked me, any LINQy problem that needs to keep state would be better written off as a generator rather than trying to smash it down to the constraints of using LINQ. Any LINQ query that relies on side effects are exactly the kind of queries you should want to avoid.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Kirk.  Hopefully it's clearer what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm disappointed that I couldn't solve this without relying on side-effects in a `GroupBy` statement, but I think this fulfills what you asked:

```
var rnd = new Random(0);
//make a list of mock messages
var individualMessages = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 1000)
    .Select(_ => Enumerable
        .Range(0, rnd.Next(1,100))
        .Select(__ => (byte)rnd.Next(255))
        .ToArray())
    .ToList();

var maxMessageSize = 1000;

var total = 0;
var groupingNum = 0;
var aggregatedMessages = individualMessages
    .GroupBy(x => {
        total += x.Length;
        if(total > maxMessageSize){
            groupingNum++;
            total = x.Length;
        }
        return groupingNum;
    })
    .Select(x => x.SelectMany(v => v).ToArray())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Well, it certainly adds to my understanding of Linq, but it doesn't seem to have much to do with my problem statement.